# c# DataTable Adding Data from Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable being populated however one of the fields is a drop down list which is derived from a database connection. When I click add it always add the same data despite my selection and then removes the first item in the list.

ASPX Code

```
<asp:TableCell><asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="txtProduct"></asp:DropDownList></asp:TableCell>
```

CS Code for Dropdown List

```
public void Fill1()
{
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM2Sage"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products", _con))
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader ddlValues;
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        txtProduct.DataSource = ddlValues;
        txtProduct.DataValueField = "Description";
        txtProduct.DataTextField = "Description";
        txtProduct.DataBind();

        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts as to how to fix this?

Comment: A sidenote: you are naming a DropDownList `txtProduct`? I would assume that a control with this ID is a Textbox. To your question: are you binding the DropDownList only if `!Page.IsPostBack`?

Comment: I think you'll find that the call to `DataBind` resets your selection to the first item.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to call `cmd.Connection.Close` and `cmd.Connection.Dispose`, since you have the command and the connection in `using` blocks. They'll be disposed automatically.

Comment: I having a hard time understanding what you mean by "When I click add it always add the same data despite my selection and then removes the first item in the list."  Can you please expand on this some more.

Comment: You should wrap the SqlDataReader in a using clause.

Comment: @jim-mischel how do I use databind here?
@tim-schmelter its just an ID i chose does this make a differnce I have it both the page_load and the !Page.PostBack
@evan-larsen Essentially I add my row data and then when i click the the add button it adds the first item in the product dropdown and then when I go to add another the first item isn't present in the drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are calling `Fill1()` method in page load. When page is PostBack then in page load event `Fill1()` again called and your selection will be cleared. you need to this in your load event

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   Fill1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the WHERE part of your SQL statement and a way to connect the DropDownList selection to the SQL Statment.  Something like...

```
new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID = " + txtProduct.SelectedValue , _con))
```

FYI: This is for illustration only, I would never put two steps in one line of code, I would use parameters and I would add a boat load of error checking.

Comment: I have no Id to do this with i Have a ProductCode would that do the same job?